# My loss has a non-differentiable point

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gradient-descent, backpropagation

I had to design a loss function max(0,x). It's not differentiable at x=0. In order to train it with gradient descent, what should I do?

1. I have learned that subgradient can be used instead, so does it need to be changed in the code, or will pytorch/tf calculate subgradient automatically?
2. Or use surrogate loss, so what kind of surrogate loss is there for my loss?

Comment: Your $\max(0,x)$ is a [*rectifier* or *ReLU*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)) activation function.  One of many alternatives is the *softplus* or *SmoothReLU* function $\log_e(\exp(x)+1)$ which for large positive $x$ is close to $x$ while for large negative $x$ is close to $0$ but always has a positive derivative; you can adjust its sharpness with a parameter $k$ by using $\frac1k\log_e(\exp(kx)+1)$ which has a value of $\frac1k$ when $x=0$

Comment: Thank you for your advice, It helped me a lot！